# Enable VM Basic Metrics via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to enable basic metrics gathering via ARM template for a Ubunutu 14.04 machine

I have a section like the below in my vm section of the template.

```
"resources": [  {
      "name": "Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings",
      "type": "extensions",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "AzureDiagnostics"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
        "type": "LinuxDiagnostic",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.3",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "protectedSettings": {
          "storageAccountName": "[parameters('metricsStorageAccountName')]",
          "storageAccountKey": "[listkeys(variables('accountid'), variables('apiVersion')).key1]",
          "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net"
        }
      }
    }]
```

I have attempted to export a template from the portal in an attempt to reverse engineer the approach, but the exported template doesn't contain any diagnostics sections.

What else is required so that basic metrics are enabled and I'm able to create alerts on the vm?

Answer (score 3):

The export template option does not include the `LinuxDiagnostics` extension, and we have to add it manually to the template.

The template that you specified:

```
"resources": [  {
  "name": "Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings",
  "type": "extensions",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "AzureDiagnostics"
  },
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
    "type": "LinuxDiagnostic",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.3",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "protectedSettings": {
      "storageAccountName": "[parameters('metricsStorageAccountName')]",
      "storageAccountKey": "[listkeys(variables('accountid'), variables('apiVersion')).key1]",
      "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net"
    }
  }
}]
```

Would add the extension, but you will not be able to view the monitoring graphs on the azure portal, and neither will you be able to create any alert rules, as mentioned in the support document here(under the Important notice header):
[Linux Diagnostics Github page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/Diagnostic#important-notice)

But there is a workaround to add the extension so as to be able to view the graphs. For this I created 2 VM's and added the extension on the first VM using the portal, and the second VM using the template format as shown above.Next, i used the Azure CLI, got the extension details for both in JSON format. Here's the details for the first VM's extension:

```
C:\Users\gkapagun\Downloads\ExportedTemplate>azure vm extension get --json <resource-group-name> <vm-name>
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vm-name>/extensions/LinuxDiagnostic",
    "name": "LinuxDiagnostic",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "location": "eastus2",
    "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
    "virtualMachineExtensionType": "LinuxDiagnostic",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.3",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
      "StorageAccount": "<storage-account-name>",
      "xmlCfg": "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"
    },
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
  }
]

C:\Users\gkapagun\Downloads\ExportedTemplate>
```

And for the second VM:

```
C:\Users\gkapagun\Downloads\ExportedTemplate>azure vm extension get --json <resource-group-name> <vm-name>
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vm-name>/extensions/LinuxDiagnostic",
    "name": "LinuxDiagnostic",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "location": "eastus2",
    "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
    "virtualMachineExtensionType": "LinuxDiagnostic",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.3",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
  }
]

C:\Users\gkapagun\Downloads\ExportedTemplate>
```

The difference is the way the settings is provided, especially the `xmlCfg` key.

The `xmlCfg` is nothing but a base64 encoded string consisting of how the metrics are to be collected. On decoding, i was able to obtain the following XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WadCfg>
   <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
      <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Warning" />
      <PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\AvailableMemory" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Bytes">
            <annotation displayName="Memory available" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\PercentAvailableMemory" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="Mem. percent available" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\UsedMemory" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Bytes">
            <annotation displayName="Memory used" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\PercentUsedMemory" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="Memory percentage" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\PercentUsedByCache" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="Mem. used by cache" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\PagesPerSec" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="CountPerSecond">
            <annotation displayName="Pages" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\PagesReadPerSec" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="CountPerSecond">
            <annotation displayName="Page reads" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\PagesWrittenPerSec" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="CountPerSecond">
            <annotation displayName="Page writes" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\AvailableSwap" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Bytes">
            <annotation displayName="Swap available" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\PercentAvailableSwap" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="Swap percent available" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\UsedSwap" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Bytes">
            <annotation displayName="Swap used" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\PercentUsedSwap" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="Swap percent used" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor\PercentIdleTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="CPU idle time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor\PercentUserTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="CPU user time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor\PercentNiceTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="CPU nice time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor\PercentPrivilegedTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="CPU privileged time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor\PercentInterruptTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="CPU interrupt time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor\PercentDPCTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="CPU DPC time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor\PercentProcessorTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="CPU percentage guest OS" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor\PercentIOWaitTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Percent">
            <annotation displayName="CPU IO wait time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\BytesPerSecond" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="BytesPerSecond">
            <annotation displayName="Disk total bytes" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\ReadBytesPerSecond" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="BytesPerSecond">
            <annotation displayName="Disk read guest OS" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\WriteBytesPerSecond" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="BytesPerSecond">
            <annotation displayName="Disk write guest OS" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\TransfersPerSecond" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="CountPerSecond">
            <annotation displayName="Disk transfers" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\ReadsPerSecond" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="CountPerSecond">
            <annotation displayName="Disk reads" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\WritesPerSecond" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="CountPerSecond">
            <annotation displayName="Disk writes" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\AverageReadTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Seconds">
            <annotation displayName="Disk read time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\AverageWriteTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Seconds">
            <annotation displayName="Disk write time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\AverageTransferTime" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Seconds">
            <annotation displayName="Disk transfer time" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk\AverageDiskQueueLength" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Count">
            <annotation displayName="Disk queue length" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\NetworkInterface\BytesTransmitted" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Bytes">
            <annotation displayName="Network out guest OS" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\NetworkInterface\BytesReceived" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Bytes">
            <annotation displayName="Network in guest OS" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\NetworkInterface\PacketsTransmitted" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Count">
            <annotation displayName="Packets sent" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\NetworkInterface\PacketsReceived" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Count">
            <annotation displayName="Packets received" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\NetworkInterface\BytesTotal" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Bytes">
            <annotation displayName="Network total bytes" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\NetworkInterface\TotalRxErrors" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Count">
            <annotation displayName="Packets received errors" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\NetworkInterface\TotalTxErrors" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Count">
            <annotation displayName="Packets sent errors" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
         <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\NetworkInterface\TotalCollisions" sampleRate="PT15S" unit="Count">
            <annotation displayName="Network collisions" locale="en-us" />
         </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      </PerformanceCounters>
      <Metrics resourceId="<vm URI>">
         <MetricAggregation scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1H" />
         <MetricAggregation scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" />
      </Metrics>
   </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
</WadCfg>
```

So the resource template for the extension must be:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachine_name'),'/LinuxDiagnostic')]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachine_name'))]"],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
        "type": "LinuxDiagnostic",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.3",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion":true,
        "settings": {
            "storageAccount" : "[parameters('storageAccount_name')]",
            "xmlCfg" : "[parameters('extensionXMLCfg')]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "storageAccountName": "[parameters('storageAccount_name')]",
            "storageAccountKey": "<key>",
            "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net"
        }
    }
}
```

Where the parameter `extensionXMLCfg` is a base64 encoded XML data with the VM URI specified.

With this you can add alertrules as well in the templates.